# Trying to get an else statement to return a webpage

Tags: c#, html, class, asp.net-mvc-5

Shopping Cart class

```
    public int AddToCart(Product product)
    {
```

checks if there is stock available and is the if statement that connects to the else that i want to return a view

```
        if (product.productStock < 1)
        {

            // Get the matching cart and item instances
            var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
                c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                && c.ProductId == product.productId);

            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
                cartItem = new Cart
                {
                    ProductId = product.productId,
                    CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                    Count = 1,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    CPName = product.productName,
                    CPPrice = product.Price

                };
                storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
                //1 will be taken from the total product stock
                product.productStock = product.productStock - 1;

            }

            else
            {
                // If the item does exist in the cart, 
                // then add one to the quantity
                cartItem.Count++;
                //1 will be taken from the total product stock
                product.productStock = product.productStock - 1;

            }
            // Save changes
            storeDB.SaveChanges();

            return cartItem.Count;
        }
        else
        {
```

trying to get this to return the following view

```
            return ...
        }
    }
```

out of stock View

this view is stored in a shoppingcart folder

```
     @{
        ViewBag.Title = "outofstock";
       }

 <h2>Sorry this item is out of stock please select another</h2>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'">Return to products page</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Redirect function to take the user to the URL of your choice

```
Redirect("http://www.yourdomain.com/page");
```

Comment: Redirect is part of standard MVC Controller. Where are you writing this method? Is it not a controller?